Acidic strength of hydrogen halides
We all know that acidic strength of hydrogen halides increase down the group. So, is it reasonable to assume that fluoride ion is Thermodynamically less stable than other halide ions?
Or are there other parameters that affect the acidic strength of halides, which do not affect thermodynamic stability? But I don't think there are other factors on the basis of this question and answer and also because basic character is a thermodynamic parameter:
Rationalizing Strength of Binary Halogen Acids with MO Theory

I don't think you read well what you link, and there were better posts about this topic here. More importantly, if you checked electron affinities (they aren't called "stability"), you'd see that they hardly correlate with acidity.

This question is similar to: Is HF the least acidic hydrogen halide?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thermodynamic stability is not really an intrinsic property of anything, including halide ions. It depends on environment. All halide ions from fluoride to iodide are stable in the environment of an aqueous solution containing alkali metal or ammonium counterions (other metals may precipitate some of these ions, as with calcium fluoride or silver chloride; astatide ion, in addition to the astatine decaying radioactively, apparently reduces the water solvent).
And hydrogen fluoride is not a weak acid in the sense that acetic acid or an  ammonium salt is. As described by Giguere and Turrell[1], hydrogen fluoride dissociates completely in water, only to have the ions remain bound through hydrogen bonding to form what are in effect molecules of $\ce{H3OF}$ (or more accurately, $\ce{H2OHF}$). It is this $\ce{H3OF}$ that is the true weak acid, whose formation by hydrolysis accounts for alkali-metal fluorides being basic in aqueous solutions.
Reference

Paul A. Giguere, Sylvia Turrell. "The nature of hydrofluoric acid. A spectroscopic study of the proton-transfer complex $\ce{H3O^+}\cdot\cdot\cdot\ce{F-}$". J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1980, 102, 17, 5473–5477. https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00537a008.


Thanks a lot Oscar Lanzi, this had been plaguing me for a long time. Also, could you tell me why this phenomenon is negligible for other halides? I don't have authorization to access the paper you mentioned...

"why this phenomenon is negligible for other halides?" Second-period nonmetals have compact valence shells and give good overlap with hydrogen for hydrogen bonds.
